# Extending Rails Application Controllers for Active Admin and devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, devise-token-auth

I am trying to implement both devise_token_auth and Active Admin in my rails api back-end.

There are pretty clear instructions on the [devise_token_auth FAQ](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/docs/faq.md#im-having-trouble-using-this-gem-alongside-activeadmin) explaining how to implement the two together - it requires two different Application Controller classes.

```
# app/controllers/api_controller.rb
# API routes extend from this controller
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
# leave this for ActiveAdmin, and any other non-api routes
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

I have both of these controllers in my app, but I can't figure out how to inherit from them for the controllers for Active Admin and devise_token_auth.

I'm sure I am  missing something basic here, because in all of the answers that I've seen about this on StackOverflow, it seems assumed that I know how to do this.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:**

Restating the problem, because I don't think I was clear the first time. Right now, both Active Admin and devise_token_auth are using the ApplicationController, even though I created the ApiController too. How do I make devise_token_auth use the ApiController?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? ActiveAdmin is mounted as an engine, so you shouldn't have to extend any controller. For your API controllers, you just extend the `ApiController` class. Can you provide more details on the problem you are facing? Or are you looking for an example?

Comment: You are right, I don't think I was clear in stating my problem. I just updated the question, but problem is that right now both Active Admin and devise_token_auth are using the ApplicationController, even though I created the ApiController too. How do I make devise_token_auth use the ApiController? An example would be perfect, so I could see how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a separate namespace, that will make your code cleaner and better organized. However it is not mandatory. All you need to do is in your controllers for the APIs, extend your `ApiController` instead of `ActionController::Base`.

For example, here's a base API controller,

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  include Pundit
end
```

and a sample controller that extends it and uses devise_token_auth as a result.

```
class Api::V1::SampleController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    render json: { success: true, email: current_user.email }, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Here's a sample project that has separate web and API controllers https://github.com/anujmiddha/rails-api-web-sample

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are doing here that I am not that is making this work. How does DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create (for example) know to use the BaseController?

Comment: If you check out the source code for [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/registrations_controller.rb), you can see that the RegistrationsController extends [DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/application_controller.rb) which in turn extends the DeviseController. These will still be extending the same classes, irrespective of what classes you define in your code.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put in to creating the sample project - thank you! Unfortunately, I think this comment is my real answer - I can't extend RegistrationsController from my APIController. I am probably just going to remove Active Admin from my project altogether and find another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to [devise_token_auth demo example](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth_demo) in devise_token_auth's readme on github.

the main difference between your case and the demo app is that you will use `ApiController` instead of `ApplicationController`. also, you have to add `devise_token_auth` attributes to the corresponding model, (for example, if you want to use `devise_token_auth` with users, you have to add the attributes to the `users` table and `before_action: authenticate_user!` to `UsersController`.).

Comment: I am not having a problem getting token_auth_demo working as in the example. I can get it working fine using ApplicationController. My issue is getting it to use ApiController instead. Is it simply a matter of the namespacing? I am definitely missing something here, but I am mystified as to what it is.